# File gets cleared when try to write to it

Tags: python, file

I am try to make it possible to save progress in my python game put the following line is giving me problems:

```
dataW = open("data.dat","wb")
```

How can I stop this line from clearing my file.

Comment: From the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open): *The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (**truncating the file if it already exists**), and 'a' for appending*. Bold emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in *write* mode:

> `'w'` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be
>   **erased**)

*Emphasis mine*

You meant to use the *append* mode:

> `'a'` opens the file for appending